# Python3: File path problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, filepath

Suppose  my `Python3` project structure is :

```
Project
 | App.py
 | AFolder
 |   | tool.py
 |   | token.json
```

In `tool.py`, I use `os.path.exists('token.json')` to check whether the Json file exits. As expected, it returns **true**.

```
def check():
   return os.path.exists('token.json')
```

However, when I call this in `App.py`, it returns **false**.

It seems file path is different when calling functions between modules. How to solve it ?

Comment: Just use `AFolder/token.json`

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the concept of the ["working directory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), which you can access via [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd).  If you printed `os.getcwd()` inside `check()`, you'd see that what it returns differs between when you call it from inside tool.py and inside App.py.  If you specify relative paths, it's assumed they're relative from the cwd, and since the cwd changes, the location the tests check also changes.  This explains the difference.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where the file in which you've written `os.path.exists( . . .` is.  What matters is where you are when you import and call the function.

So, use the full path when you check whether the file exists.

```
def check():
   directory_to_file = '/home/place/where/i/store/files/'
   return os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory_to_file, 'token.json'))
   # Making the check relative to current path will be more portable:
   # return os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'token.json')
```

This will allow the `check` function to work *anywhere*!

Comment: Making the check relative to current path will be more portable. I edited this answer with details. I'll post a separate answer if needed.